# Finding number of cells visited in given explanation

Tags: python, algorithm

This is a Hackerrank question.

Babai is standing in the top left cell (1,1) of an N*M table. The table has N rows and M columns.

Initially he is facing its right cell. He moves in the table in the following manner:

> 1. He moves one step forward
> 2. He turns to its right
> 3. If moving forward makes him exit the boundaries of the table, or causes him to reach a visited cell, he turns to its right.

He moves around the table and visits as many cells as he can. Your task is to find out the number of cells that he visits before he stops.

Here's a sample of Babai's steps on a 9x9 grid. The value at each cell denotes the step number.

```
1  2 55 54 51 50 47 46 45 
4  3 56 53 52 49 48 43 44 
5  6 57 58 79 78 77 42 41 
8  7 60 59 80 75 76 39 40 
9 10 61 62 81 74 73 38 37 
12 11 64 63 68 69 72 35 36 
13 14 65 66 67 70 71 34 33 
16 15 20 21 24 25 28 29 32 
17 18 19 22 23 26 27 30 31
```

**Input:**
The input contains two integers N and M separated by a line. N and M are between 1 and 100.

**Output:**
Print a single integer which is the answer to the test-case

**Sample input #00:**

```
3
3
```

**Sample output #00:**

```
9
```

**Sample input #01:**

```
7
4
```

**Sample output #01:**

```
18
```

**Actual query:**

Now one answer that has come to my mind is about marking the visited nodes in the matrix, and following up the rules of movement. Then increment the counter on every move, and printing it at last.

But I found another answer that does not use such code complexity. I am not getting it. Can you explain?

```
def move(n, m):
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 0
    elif m == 1 and n == 1:
        return 1
    elif (n % 2 == 1):
        return 2 * n + move(m-2, n)
    else:
        return 2 * n


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input("Enter number 1-100: "))
    m = int(input("Enter another number 1-100: "))
    print move(n, m)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is almost correct.

It identifies 4 cases. The first two are trivial:

```
if m == 0 or n == 0:
    return 0
elif m == 1 and n == 1:
    return 1
```

Those are obviously correct return values, and also serve as an end point to the recursion that is used in the third case.

```
elif (n % 2 == 1):
    return 2 * n + move(m-2, n)
else:
    return 2 * n
```

Let's first look at the last case. This is when *n* (the number of rows) is even. As you can see in this picture, Babai gets stuck in the bottom left corner when *n* is 4:

[image: Odd rows]

It is not hard to see that the same would have happened on a 6-row grid, or any even-rowed grid. In all these cases, the first two columns of the grid match the collection of visited cells. As in each column there are *n* cells, the solution is indeed *2n*.

Now the most tricky case is when *n* is odd. In that case Balai will also pass through the first two column cells, but the last one visited will not be the corner one, but the one at the right of it:

[image: Even rows]

Again, it is not difficult to see that this is not only true for the 5 rows in the image, but for any odd-rowed grid.

Now look at the area Babai is about to enter in: it is a grid with size *m-2* columns and *n* rows. It is almost like starting a new puzzle from scratch, except that Babai starts at the bottom-left of the grid, and not the top-left. Now imagine that we turn the whole grid clockwise:

[image: Turned grid]

Now, the cell Babai is about to enter is *exactly* where he would enter in a brand new grid. Further more, as he enters the corner cell of that "new" grid, he has to turn to his right ... until he finds a free cell, which is the cell in the second column. This is the same path Babai would take in a new puzzle. So, ... we could leave the solution of the number of steps to a recursive call, where we need to swap the number of columns and rows to mimic the 90° turn we did.

One may cast a doubt on whether this really is the same thing, because the movement rules might work differently now. But that is not the case. Whichever direction you are facing: turning right is the same movement. It does not matter if your world turns while you do that: it leads you to the same spot. So, yes, we may turn the grid without effect on the movement rules.

And so we have two parts in the calculation:

1. the two columns where each cell was visited: *2n*
2. the solution of a grid with *m-2* rows(!) and *2n* columns(!)

This can be written as the recursive formula that is in case 3 of the code:

```
return 2 * n + move(m-2, n)
```

#### The problem with this code

The end point for the recursion is not good enough. Imagine we have an input with *n* = 1 and *m* = 2. This is a very trivial case, and it is clear the answer should be 2.

As case 1 and 2 are not applicable, and *n* is odd, it is a case 3: the recursive call will be `move(m-2,n)`, which is `move(-1,1)`, which is ... a problem, because in the recursive call the first two cases are still not applicable, and so this turns into an endless chain of recursive calls.

#### Solution

To fix it, change the second condition and return value as follows (notice the `or`):

```
elif n == 1 or m == 1:
    return n * m
```

This is correct: if the grid has one row or column, Babai will walk along that line and visit all its cells (so the whole 1 dimensional grid), which has indeed *m.n* cells.

This case can even absorb the first case, since there the solution is 0. And so the corrected code is:

```
def move(n, m):
    if m < 2 or n < 2:
        return n * m
    elif (n % 2 == 1):
        return 2 * n + move(m-2, n)
    else:
        return 2 * n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input("Enter number 1-100: "))
    m = int(input("Enter another number 1-100: "))
    print move(n, m)
```

We can now be sure that the recursion will stop: if *n* < 2 or *m* < 2, then one of the first two cases will be true, and no further recursive calls will be made. This means the recursive call `move(m-2, n)` is safe now. It reduces the grid size in every next call, but will never get into the negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. How did you quickly find it out? Tell me the trick/approach.

Comment: When there is a recursive call, it means that the algorithm for solving a smaller variant of the problem is the same as the original problem. Normally, when you don't have any code, this is something to detect yourself, which may take more time, but here it was already given, so it was more "easy" to see how that sub-problem had to be like a new, but smaller, problem. Then, a bit later, I saw the incorrectness, because I saw the `-2` in the recursive call. This was an alarm bell: the number should never become negative, but with steps of two you have to stop the recursion at 0 **and** 1.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the `9x9` matrix that you showed. The base conditions are trivial.

First suppose that N is even. Lets say 8. Then the path shall terminate at the cell that is marked 16 because all the 3 neighbouring cells would be already visited and no further path would be possible. Hence `2*N`.

Now if N is odd (say 9), then after travelling the 1st two columns, he would be sitting on the cell marked 19 and facing upwards. Hence the problem is now reduced from `(N,M)` matrix to `(M-2,N)` matrix.
Note that now since he is facing upwards, the rows and columns get interchanged. Hence `2*N + move(M-2, N)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Abhi.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be further optimized when the N*M table contains at least  5 rows and 5 columns, calculate the number of node visits in the outer layer of the grid consisting 4 rows and 4 columns and then make a recursive call for N-4,M-4. The code for the same is

```
def move(n, m):
   if m < 2 or n < 2:
     return n * m
   elif m > 4 and n > 4
     return (4*(n+m)) - 16 + move(n-4,m-4)
   elif (n % 2 == 1):
     return 2 * n + move(m-2, n)
   else:
     return 2 * n
```

Comment: Care to explain a bit more how your logic will work correctly in this case?

Comment: If we see the above `9x9` matrix, all the visits from 1->56 covers 2 outer layers of the matrix and starting from 57 the same sub problem repeats with N-4 rows and N-4 columns. The total visits in the outermost 2 layers(including 2 rows each top and bottom side and 2 columns each left and right side) equals to `4*(N + M) - 16` where N is num of rows, M is num of columns and 16 is common nodes in all the outermost 4 rows and columns